# Socket not sending entire contents on Linux (ubuntu)

Tags: c++, linux, sockets, gcc, 64-bit

I've encountered an issue when sending large segments of data through a TCP socket, having spend about 3 days trying to pick apart the issue and failing I decided it was best to turn here for help / advice.

**My Project**
I've written a basic HTTP server which (slightly irrelevant) can run lua scripts to output pages. This all works perfectly fine under Windows (32 bit).

**The Problem**

When sending medium/large files (anything from roughly 8000 bytes and above appears to have issues) over the TCP socket on Ubuntu Linux(64bit), they appear to cut out at different lengths (the result displayed in the browser is a value between 8000 and 10200 bytes. When I check the return value of the send function it's exactly `9926` bytes every time the send ends. No error.

Smaller files send absolutely fine, and there are no issues under windows. Going on this information I thought it could be a buffer size issues, so I did

```
cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_mem
```

which outputted `188416  192512  196608`

those numbers are far above 9926 so I assume that isn't the problem.

I'm using [CSimpleSockets](http://sockets.carrierlabs.com/classCSimpleSocket.html) as a socket library, I haven't had any issues before. In case the issue is inside of this library the code I dug around for what the send function used under unix is:

```
#define SEND(a,b,c,d)          send(a, (const int8 *)b, c, d)

send(socket, buffer, bytestosend, 0);
```

buffer gets cast from a `const char *` to `const unsigned char*` to `const int8 *` before getting passed to the OS to be sent.

OK, I think that covers everything I checked. If you need any more information or I've missed anything glaringly obvious I'll do my best to provide. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is that send does not guarantee to send the amount of data passed to it.

It has internal buffers that can fill, socket parameters that affect buffers, etc. You need to note how many bytes were sent, wait for a few milliseconds (for the send to move data over the wire and empty the buffer), then send the remaining data. There is no automatic way to do this and you'll need to write a bit of logic which advances your buffer by the amount of bytes that were actually sent.

Comment: By the way the fact that this is Linux or 64 bit has nothing to do with it. You're just seeing this now because the buffer there is a bit smaller. Try to send 1 MB of data from your Windows side and see the exact same thing happening (probably at 32 kb or 64 kb of data)

Answer (score 2):

Are you using blocking or non-blocking sockets? If you're using non-blocking sockets, you **must** (and with blocking sockets, you *should*) check for a short `send` (one where the return value is fewer than the number of bytes you meant to send).

Comment: Thanks, I was using blocking sockets but what you said is correct however the other guy got there first.

Comment: With blocking sockets, you should only see a short send if the send is interrupted by a signal.

Comment: The Socket library I'm using has a while loop within it to continue sending if it's interrupted by a signal, so perhaps there's a bug in it or something. I'll email the developer. Thanks again for your help